# NextJS 14 site working in development but not in vercel

Tags: next.js, vercel

I have a page(server component) that fetches some data from a route handler(`/api/v1/bookings/get`) in my app.

Running my site with <kbd>next dev --turbo</kbd> works fine and does not give any errors but when deploying to vercel, I get the error `Application error: a server-side exception has occurred (see the server logs for more information)`

Looking at my logs, I see a warning that says that the route `/api/v1/bookings/get` was not found, which is weird because it seems to have been build when deploying the project as per the deployment summary on vercel.
[image: Deployment summary]

After the `404` I see a error that tells my front end was unable to parse the response returned(which should be in JSON but is probably in **HTML** since the API route was not found)
[image: errors list]
[image: error closeup]

---

For my route handler, it is a simple file that gets all the 'rides' for a specific user(determined by their email). It's code is:

```js
import { auth, currentUser } from "@clerk/nextjs/server";
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

export async function GET() {
  const user = await currentUser();
  auth().protect();

  try {
    const bookings = await prisma.ride.findMany({
      where: {
        rider: {
          email: user?.primaryEmailAddress?.emailAddress,
        }
      }
    });

    return new Response(JSON.stringify({bookings}), {
      status: 200,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);

    return new Response(JSON.stringify(error), {
      status: 500,
    });
  }
}
```

The front end looks like:

```
import booking from "@/types/bookings";
import {
  Card,
  CardContent,
  CardDescription,
  CardFooter,
  CardTitle,
} from "../ui/card";
import Link from "next/link";
import { Button } from "../ui/button";

export default async function Bookings() {
  const res = await fetch(process.env.BASE_URL + "/api/v1/bookings/get", {
    next: {
      revalidate: 60,
    },
  });
  const response: { bookings: booking[] } = await res.json();
  const bookings = response.bookings;
  return (
    <div className="p-4 m-4">
      <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold">Previous bookings</h1>
      <div className="grid grid-cols-2 grid-rows-5 gap-2">
        {bookings.length > 0 ? (
          bookings.map((booking) => (
            <Card key={booking.id}>
              <CardTitle>{booking.name}</CardTitle>
              <CardDescription>
                {new Date(booking.created).toLocaleDateString()}
              </CardDescription>
              <CardContent>
                A {booking.duration} hour trip with {booking.people} people and{" "}
                {booking.driver && booking.driver.name} as driver.
              </CardContent>
              <CardFooter>
                From {booking.startLocation && booking.startLocation.city} to{" "}
                {booking.endLocation && booking.endLocation.city}
              </CardFooter>
            </Card>
          ))
        ) : (
          <div>
            <p>You don&apos;t have any bookings yet. Make your first!</p>
            <Link href={"/dashboard/book"}>
              <Button variant={"secondary"}>Book a ride.</Button>
            </Link>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

### I manually set the base URL variable in my `.env` file.

Searching for a fix on Google, I saw a few people suggesting purging the cache(on Vercel's side), which I tried but didn't work, I also redeployed afterwards.

File structure:
[image: file structure]

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Update the question to include the code of the Server Component that fetches the data

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by a malformed request URL.
To run the GET function you must be request with GET method.

Example:

```
const getBookings = async () => {

try {
  const res = await fetch('http://<your-site-host>/api/v1/bookings',{
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json'
    }
  })
  if(res?.ok){
    console.log(res)
  }else{
    console.log("Oops! Something is wrong.")
  }
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
}
```

}

Your logs contains a item with a GET method request to **/api/v1/bookings/get** but to correct path is **/api/v1/bookings**

[For more examples please look for official docs.](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route)